# Lemma on lattices

Tags: lattice-orders

I read a lemma on lattices that says in every lattice $(P, \subseteq)$  for all $x,y \in P$ we have:

$x \subseteq x \cup y  \land x \subseteq x \cup y $

But I do not get why this is. Take for example $\subseteq$ defined as the divisor |. Then $10 \cup 15 = 5$, but I do not think $10 | 5$, neither $15 | 5$. What am I overlooking? Thanks a lot for the explanation already!

EDIT: $\subseteq$ and $\cup$ are supposed to be the square onces, but I can't find them in Mathjax.

Comment: $10\cup 15=30$, not $5$: it’s the least common multiple. $10\cap 15=5$.

Comment: Ah that completely explains it indeed!

Comment: You want `\sqcup` ($\sqcup$), `\sqcap` ($\sqcap$), and `\sqsubseteq` ($\sqsubseteq$).